# How I can remove repetition when dealing with incompatible types in an if/else?

Tags: rust

I have a method `decode_message` that has 2 implementations, one is for `BufReader<Read>` the other is `BufReader<Read + Seek>`. Specialisation is enabled.

```
if is_stdin {
    let mut reader = BufReader::with_capacity(1000, io::stdin());
    decode_message(reader)
} else {
    let filename = &args[1];
    let mut reader = BufReader::with_capacity(1000, File::open(filename).unwrap());
    decode_message(reader)
};
```

The code above works, but it is annoying that I have to repeat `decode_message` in each branch.

Comment: *Specialisation is enabled* — why do you believe that specialization has anything to do with this problem?

Comment: @Shepmaster  So that I hope the solution would cause `decode_message` to specialise the type of `BufReader` as well, rather than fallback to the default.

Comment: That does not look like specialisation, just monomorphism. And there is hardly a better way to do that than what you already have. Making `reader` a trait object would remove the repetition, but that would induce a runtime cost.

Comment: Also note that you can [`lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) stdin to get a reader that implements `BufRead`. The concerns would be the same however.

Comment: @E_net4 How is `lock` compared to `BufReader`?

Comment: @E_net4 I have to `#![feature(specialization)]` to get my code work. Why is not specialization?

Comment: @colinfang I meant to say that the culprit of the question does not have to do with specialization.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your question shows, specialization is not the culprit, it's just the use of monomorphisms: the `reader` bindings defined in the two conditional scopes, given the definition of `BufReader::new`, will be different and cannot be assigned to the same binding. Each time a run-time condition leads to the divergence of value types, such as in this case, they will also lead to code routines that cannot be shared among them.

Of course, there is an exception to this: trait objects have their concrete type erased, and so a binding `reader: BufReader<Box<Read>>`, or even `reader: Box<BufRead>`, could hold any of the two readers in the conditional statements. However, the resulting code would likely not perform better, since it would induce a runtime cost from method resolution, and prevent some ahead-of-time optimizations.

Therefore, there is hardly a better way to do that than what you already have.
In fact, a good pattern here has already been applied in your example: you can use monomorphic functions to contain the remaining logic that diverged from monomorphism, until it converges to the same type. With it, you only have to repeat a `decode_message()` call instead of everything in it.

Comment: If I use trait object, i.e. cast both to `BufReader<Box<Read>>`, does it prevent the monomorphisms? I.e, does `decode_message` always go via `Read` route and never `Read + Seek`?

Comment: @colinfang That would be a grey area. The feature is not stabilized, and there isn't much information about whether trait objects can follow specializations. In this particular case, you are much better off not using trait objects. Otherwise, the [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) would be the best (albeit more exhausting) source of information about how specialization works (and should work).